# Other language for UISearchBar

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, swift4

I have got a problem with UI SearchBar in swift. My problem is I want to use searchbar to find the word in Table View Cell. The word is not an English word.

Here is my code.

```
if ((searchText.contains("ၵ"))) {

    filteredArray = homeDict.filter { $0._meaning.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText) }
    }else{
    filteredArray = homeDict.filter { $0._word.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText) }
    }
    if(filteredArray.count == 0){
        searchActive = false;
    } else {
        searchActive = true;
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
```

That is work for only one word of "ၵ". I want to search, if the word in Searchbar the same as any word in Table View Cell, display result in cell row.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this function uses the current Locale, not necessarily the locale that the letters might be in.  Try testing with the device in the locale of the language the strings are in to check.

You could probably make your own contains with [`func lowercased(with locale: Locale?) -> String`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1417298-lowercased)

You would need to know the locale the user intended the search to be in.  You could also use this function to test what the lowercase version of a string is in various locales (to test the theory above).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try like your said and reply you soon.